# How to convert JS object to string representing a valid Python dict?

Tags: javascript, python, dictionary, code-generation

I need to write code that takes a JavaScript object and writes out a string that is a valid, nice-looking Python3 dict. If possible, I wish to do this with no external dependencies.

My current implementation is as follows:

```js
const TRUE_PLACEHOLDER = "__replace_me_true__";
const FALSE_PLACEHOLDER = "__replace_me_false__";
const booleanToPlaceholderReplacer = (key, val) =>
  val === true ? TRUE_PLACEHOLDER : val === false ? FALSE_PLACEHOLDER : val;

const objToPythonDictStr = (obj) =>
  JSON.stringify(obj, booleanToPlaceholderReplacer, 4)
    .replaceAll(`"${TRUE_PLACEHOLDER}"`, "True")
    .replaceAll(`"${FALSE_PLACEHOLDER}"`, "False");
```

An example result of `objToPythonDictStr` demonstrating that it seems to work well:

```
>>  console.log(objToPythonDictStr({foo: 1, bar: false, baz: { baz2: true }}))

{
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": False,
    "baz": {
        "baz2": True
    }
}
```

(Note: one obvious issue with my code is that if either of the placeholder strings are used as actual strings in the data, they'll get replaced incorrectly. This is quite unlikely in my use case and I'm okay with that risk, but I'm open to a better implementation which would remove this flaw if it doesn't lead to a much more complex implementation.)

Assuming that the object passed to `objToPythonDictStr` is a JSON-serializable object, is my `objToPythonDictStr` reasonable and correct?

Specifically, are there any incompatibilities in the output of JSON serialization and Python dict syntax, other than boolean representation, which will cause issues when using the hacky methodology shown above?

Comment: You should probably use json.loads but your code looks like it does work.

Comment: What is the error in your code? Your code seems to work fine. If it's still not what you expect as a result, it seems to be a semantic error, what is the expected output?

Comment: See the question body above, I edited the direct questions at the end to provide a bit more clarity. The specific question is if there are any syntactical oddities in JSON output or in Python dict syntax that would cause my methodology to unexpectedly fail (since it is quite hacky).

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) (e.g. why is the second parameter of `JSON.stringify()` named `replacer`?)

Answer (score 2):

Python already offers a `json.loads(str)` method for parsing valid JSON strings into Python objects, there is no reason to do it JS-side.

At least one thing your function is missing is the difference between null value in JSON strings and Python equivalent of None

Comment: I agree with you in general, though in this case, as noted above, I specifically need to generate a Python dict.

Comment: Well, there is at least one more difference, namely JSON strings use null while Python uses None.

Comment: Ah thank you, that's something clearly important I somehow missed and exactly what I was looking for. If you include it in your answer happy to upvote it!